# SQL inner joins not displaying data

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am new to php so please could someone take a look at this php code and explain/edit why the inner joins do not display the information required in query2.

```
<?php
{
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


    $pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); $query = "SELECT Appointment_id, Doctor_id, Patient_id, Appointment_time, Appointment_date FROM Appointment where Patient_id=$pid";
    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
    //this selects the results as rows

    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1) {}
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
        $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];

    }


   $query2 = "SELECT Doctor_id FROM Appointment INNER JOIN Doctor ON Appointment.Doctor_id=Doctor.Doctor_id";
    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

    //this selects the results as rows
    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1) {}


    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Doctor_id'] = $row['Doctor_id'];
        $_SESSION['Name'] = $row['Name'];
        $_SESSION['Room'] = $row['Room'];


    }


}
?>
```

I am requesting Doctor_id, Name and Room from the Doctor table to display the information in the Appointment table

[image]

The tables are linked together. Doctor_id is the primary key in the Doctor table and the foreign key in the Appointment table.

[image]

I need to display the Name and Room in the Appointment table.

appointment.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
        <!-- User-generated css -->
        <style>
        </style>
        <!-- User-generated js -->
        <script>
            try {

    $(function() {

    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Your javascript has an error: " + error);
  }
        </script>
     </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="d" href="login.html" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                    Back
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="d"class="ui-btn-right">
                 Home  
                </a>
                <h3>
                    Book appointment
                </h3>
           </div>

           <div data-role="content">
                <h3>
                    Select date/time:
                </h3>
                <br />
<?php
{
    mysql_connect("localhost" , "" , "") or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());


    $pid=intval($_SESSION["Patient_id"]); $query = "SELECT Appointment_id, Doctor_id, Patient_id, Appointment_time, Appointment_date FROM Appointment where Patient_id=$pid";

    //executes query on the database
    $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");
    //this selects the results as rows

    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1) {}
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['Appointment_date'] = $row['Appointment_date'];
        $_SESSION['Appointment_time'] = $row['Appointment_time'];
    }
        $query2 = "SELECT t1.*, t2.Name, t2.Room FROM Appointment AS t1
        INNER JOIN Doctor AS t2
        ON t1.Doctor_id=t2.Doctor_id";
        //executes query on the database
        $result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

        //this selects the results as rows
        $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    
        //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
        if ($num == 1) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
            print_r($row);['Doctor_id'] = $row['Doctor_id'];
            print_r($row);['Name'] = $row['Name'];
            print_r($row);['Room'] = $row['Room'];
        } else {
          // we have more than one row
        }
}
?>  

        <strong>Dates available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select date--</option>
        <option value="1"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_date'];?></option>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

        <strong>Times available</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Select time--</option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION['Appointment_time'];?></option>>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

            <strong>Doctor Name</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Name--</option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION['Name'];?></option>>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

            <strong>Doctor Room</strong>            
        <select id="Availability" name="Availability">                      
        <option value="0">--Room--</option>
        <option value="2"><?php echo $_SESSION['Room'];?></option>>
        </select>

        <br />
        <br />

                <label for="textarea1">
                Message GP
                </label>
                <textarea name="" id="textarea1" placeholder="">
                </textarea>


             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post tables structure?

Comment: Check the edit please. I've displayed the relationships if that's ok

Comment: the problem is that you should specify from what table you will take this Doctor_id, because you have a join. So change the query with  SELECT Appointment.Doctor_id....

Comment: I need to use the doctor_id to display Name and Room in the appointment table. How would i do this?

Comment: @user2216325 use `SELECT t1.Doctor_id,t2.Name,t2.Room FROM Appointment t1 INNER JOIN Doctor t2 ON t1.Doctor_id=t2.Doctor_id`

Comment: @MarCejas, that didn't work. Just displayed an error

Comment: @user2216325 what error?

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'doctor_id' in field list is ambiguous.
```

Your query2 should say:

```
"SELECT Doctor.Doctor_id FROM Appointment INNER JOIN Doctor ON Appointment.Doctor_id=Doctor.Doctor_id";
```

or

```
"SELECT Appointment.Doctor_id FROM Appointment INNER JOIN Doctor ON Appointment.Doctor_id=Doctor.Doctor_id";
```

depending on what you want to query.

Best,

Comment: also instead of using "or die ("didn't query");" use "if(!$result) { echo 'Oops: ' . mysql_error(); } else { .... }

Comment: Can you check my edited question please. I just uploaded an image

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query2 = "SELECT t1.*, t2.Name, t2.Room FROM Appointment AS t1
INNER JOIN Doctor AS t2
ON t1.Doctor_id=t2.Doctor_id";
//executes query on the database
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("didn't query");

//this selects the results as rows
$num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    
//if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
if ($num == 1) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $_SESSION['Doctor_id'] = $row['Doctor_id'];
    $_SESSION['Name'] = $row['Name'];
    $_SESSION['Room'] = $row['Room'];
} else {
  // we have more than one row
}
```

I don't understand how you can code when you can't use print_r or var_dump... here is the code you should use to debug:

```
//this selects the results as rows
    $num = mysql_num_rows ($result);    
    //if there is only 1 result returned than the data is ok 
    if ($num == 1) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        print_r($row);
    } else {
      // we have more than one row
    }
```

If you have a $row with key ['Room'], the problem is somewhere in PHP

Comment: Showing an error when i changed the Sessions. $_SESSION['t2'] = $row['t2']; :s

Comment: NO, you name tables only with t1 and t2. The coulmn names remains.

Comment: So i put your code and it still showed an error: Undefined index on those 2 session lines

Comment: try my edited code. You did nothing when the result has only one row.

Comment: you may have a inconsistent tables. Try print_r($row) to see if the script returns any row.

Comment: Just checked my tables and they all match. Any ideas?

Comment: Wht returns this SQL query? try it in phpmyadmin or other mysql client

Comment: It displays the following: Notice: Undefined index: Name in /web/stud//PHP/appointment1.php on line 92 Notice: Undefined index: Room in /web/stud/u1262082/PHP/appointment1.php on line 93 Dates available

Comment: line 92 and 93 are sessions and where it says Dates available, that is on line 101 after the closing of the php script.

Comment: No, i mean get this SQL query ant put it in phpmyadmin or other mysql client to see if any result occurs. After that you can continue to debug.

Comment: Just tried it in phpmyadmin and it displayed the result so the query 2 code seems ok.

Comment: Then try print_r($row) before $_SESSION['Doctor_id'] = $row['Doctor_id']; and see what is returned

Comment: print_r($row);$_SESSION['Room'] = $row['Room']; Like this??

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: Room in /web/stud//PHP/appointment1.php on line 91 Dates available. Thats the error i get mate

Comment: This is Notice, not error. After print_r, do you have something like array( ...) on this screen with the error?

Comment: Yes it shows: Array ( [0] => 7 [Appointment_id] => 7 [1] => 1 [Doctor_id] => 1 [2] => 20 [Patient_id] => 20 [3] => 15:00:00 [Appointment_time] => 15:00:00 [4] => 2014-05-28 [Appointment_date] => 2014-05-28 )

Comment: Hm it seems that it doesnt get t2.Room column. Try my edited answer. and if get same Notice try again print_r instead $_SESSION... rows. And update your question with this array(..)

Comment: if i put in print_r it displays undefined

Comment: I have just edited my question to display my entire code. Could you please take a look and see if i have made an error somewhere. Thank you